# EGit requires org.eclipse.team.core

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am getting this error when installing EGit:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: EGit Import Support
>   2.0.0.201206130900-r (org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group 2.0.0.201206130900-r)   Missing requirement: EGit Import Support 2.0.0.201206130900-r (org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group 2.0.0.201206130900-r) requires 'org.eclipse.team.core 3.6.100' but it could not be found

I suppose it requires the base team module to be added to Eclipse but i cannot find the download.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The "EGit Import Support" feature requires Eclipse 3.8, 4.2 or higher. Just deselect the checkbox, and installing should work.

See here about the feature: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.0#Support_for_Eclipse-SourceReferences_manifest_headers

Comment: 3.8 allows this module to be installed too

Comment: thanks!  Would it KILL the eclipse team to make their dependency error messages a bit less obscure?

Comment: @BrianTarbox In Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler), there is a "remediation" feature which should help in situations like these, see new and noteworthy: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.3M7-201305020800/news/#remediation