# Error in installing EGit in Eclipse: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

Tags: eclipse, egit

Eclipse: Indigo Service Release 1

OS: Windows 7

When I try to install EGit from the following update site http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates I get this error and I failed to find any solution so far.

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity,1.2.5.v201206130431
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design,3.3.5.v201204241156
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui,3.2.7.v201205221153
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile,3.1.2.v201206121559
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile.ui,3.1.3.v201203221637
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile,3.2.7.v201203291105
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core,1.2.5.v201205240353
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.ui,1.2.2.v201205240353
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.server.ui,1.1.100.v201202021103
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui,1.2.3.v201205240353
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.iseries.ui,1.0.2.v201202100836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw.ui,1.0.3.v201202100836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.zseries.ui,1.0.2.v201202100836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.informix.ui,1.0.3.v201202100836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.sqlserver.dbdefinition,1.0.1.v201201240505
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql,1.0.3.v201205252211
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws,1.2.4.v201203221631
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.ui,1.2.4.v201203221631
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.dbdefinition,1.0.103.v201206010214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.postgresql,1.1.1.v201205252207
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sqlite.dbdefinition,1.0.2.v201206010441
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.query,1.1.3.v201206060918
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.editor.core,1.0.2.v201205310904
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query,1.2.1.v201201250511
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result,1.1.3.v201205310911
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sql.ui,1.0.1.v201201270735
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlscrapbook,1.0.2.v201205310922
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ant,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.converter,2.5.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.2.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit,1.2.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.edit,2.5.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.editor,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.exporter,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.java,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore.editor,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2ecore,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2ecore.editor,2.5.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml.ui,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ui,2.6.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent,1.0.300.v20120522-2049
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.201.v201108161900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.core,1.2.302.v20120503_1042
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7C7h90Et1axo7RlVkOfDNlAf45E
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.core.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7B7C7LCcNBGTBfLREXcc
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-4127w312312232267
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7H7C7QCcNBHLCcJaFWRa
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.apache.derby.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-77798fBmKDQ2MoTTLwdv9ILX
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7J9Q0BWxeMcYB5KWfz-eG7qiq-sX
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.hsqldb.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-67E0AqGBM7KfNTHwKO9ILX
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7F47WFC7sRdqScnobkd4
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ingres.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-540AkF78Z7UCRAQDB
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdbc.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-4-29oB5885QBB8HKW
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdt.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-2-07w312218332612
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-544AkF7AL7MDMAQ8O
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-5477AkF7AK7_AMENEA
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.designer.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-3368s7356485C59AB
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7A7T7CDZRDKHF_HnGjOX
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-548fAkF7AL7RBJANAI
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.postgresql.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-553AkF7AK8PCRBQBP
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sap.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-540AkF7AJ7YEJBU7S
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sqlite.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-542AkF7AJ7SAKAPBF
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sybase.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7E46F9NiNc1QBgyT6T6
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7707DCcNBHJDWIYG_Ni
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.data.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-644BgJ9ECCLFTAfMO
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.ddl.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-279-78B089G8S_IRTJrXkO2_s
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.ddlgen.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7A-78F7RZHQSIqWjN1Zr
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-7N8B7CFDsn4hwBXz-0AGu5i6V36H
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.parsers.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-623BgJ9EE9ZJRDZLA
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.results.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-57B78AkF7BD7QFE9VEG
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.schemaobjecteditor.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-4208375LG5BJ93413
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.sqlbuilder.feature,1.10.0.v201201161512-79-78EVVFNOGnTeK-SY
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.converter,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit,1.2.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.2.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.editor,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.8.0.v20120606-0717
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf,2.8.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore.editor,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ui,2.7.0.v20120608-0554
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.common.fproj.enablement.jdt,3.4.0.v201108231500-377DG8s73543J5H6D66
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.server_core.feature,3.4.0.v20120503_1042-31FEe8s73554A4Fa2153
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.server_ui.feature,3.4.0.v20120503_1042-7A77FHr9xFcC2CFLZBCJMHLg7D64
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common.fproj,3.4.0.v201202292300-377F8N8s735555393B7B
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with EGit (perhaps see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087606/egit-requires-org-eclipse-team-core)), or does installing other plugins work?