# Problems with EGit installation - no Git Repository Exploring perspective and no git configuration menu under Preferences -> Team

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-12.04, egit

I installed EGit (and JGit) on my Eclipse INDIGO 3.7.2, but I cannot see the new menus that the manuals mentioned.

I cann't see the Git menu under `Windows -> Preferences -> Team`, where I should be able to configure my GIT user.
I cann't see the GIT Repository perspective either.

I installed all the "EGit P2 Repository - http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates" using `Help -> Install New Software`, except for the "EGit Plug-in Import Support" feature which has a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087606/egit-requires-org-eclipse-team-core) with its installation.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm not an experienced Eclipse user so maybe I'm missing some basic issue.

I actually need it to install [WALA](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and they recommend doing so using EGit.

Anyone ever installed EGit on a similar environment?

Comment: Did you restart after installing?

Comment: @robinst yes, and I also restarted my computer. But now I think there is something totally screwed up with my eclipse and I cannot even create simple java projects. I'll reinstall my Eclipse and see how it goes.

Comment: I meant restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many restarts and reinstallation I found out it had nothing to do specifically with EGit.
The problem was with `Help -> Check for updates` that I did before - One of the updates screws up the eclipse (I couldn't even create a simple Java project).

I'm too tired to report this in the official forums...

Comment: Did you check the Error Log view, or does the `.metadata/.log` file in your workspace folder contain anything after starting Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience using Ubuntu 12.04 Indigo package. I installed a collection of plugins, only to find nothing applied after restart - though eclipse seemed to think the plugins were installed.

I reverted to the original state and proceeded to add a few at a time . . . seems to be working . . . so far.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue after installing EGit 4.1.0 on Eclipse Kepler SR2 - Windows 7 64 bit.

Kepler SR2 comes with EGit 3.2.0 preinstalled, but I wanted the latest version.

After adding the software site: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates I installed the **Eclipse Git Team Provider**. During the install it mentioned I already had some of the components installed, and it would upgrade these - which sounded good.

After the installed was finished, I restarted Eclipse and there was nothing regarding GIT visible, nothing in preferences under Team, and the Team context menu was also missing most functions, all Git functionality was gone.

In the Error Log I saw the following stacktrace for each of my projects:

```
org.eclipse.team.core.TeamException: Could not instantiate provider org.eclipse.egit.core.GitProvider for project TestProject.
at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.mapNewProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:165)
at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.mapExistingProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:235)
at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.getProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:507)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSLightweightDecorator.isMappedToCVS(CVSLightweightDecorator.java:192)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSLightweightDecorator.decorate(CVSLightweightDecorator.java:147)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:331)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Looking at the [EGit FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ) I noticed the following:

> *Required Java Version (BREE):
>       Up to EGit 3.7 the minimum supported BREE is Java 5 though Java 6 or higher is recommended due to limitations in older Java versions.
>       Starting from EGit 4.0 the minimum supported BREE is Java 7*

I downloaded Java 8 64 bit, and installed it, and then updated my **eclipse.ini** file to include:

```
-vm
C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_60_x64/bin/javaw.exe
```

The path above will be different, depending on where you installed Java, but it needs to point at the javaw.exe file. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM for further info.

In Eclipse I added Java 8 as an installed JRE, via *Preferences -> Java - Installed JREs* and pointed it at my **C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_60_x64** directory, but this step may not be necessary.

Once all this was done, after starting Eclipse, all the Git functionality was restored.

I used Java 8, but can use Java 7, which is the minimum required from EGit 4 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Is this project shared with the CVS team provider ?
CVSLightWeightDecorator isn't an EGit class but looks like it's from the CVS team provider.

If that's the case the should be a menu entry "Team > Disconnect" on this project, if that's the case run this command and then run "Team > Share with Git" to attach the git team provider implemented by EGit.