# Dependency fail installing egit on Eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, git, ubuntu

I have this problem trying to install EGit in Eclipse Indigo on a Ubuntu 12.04:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: EGit Plug-in Import Support
>   2.3.1.201302201838-r (org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group 2.3.1.201302201838-r)
>   Missing requirement: EGit Plug-in Import Support 2.3.1.201302201838-r (org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group
>   2.3.1.201302201838-r) requires 'org.eclipse.team.core 3.6.100' but it could not be found

This is the complete Eclipse version as shown in "About" dialog:

```
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: I20110613-1736
```

I am using the default egit updates sources as it comes with Indigo installation:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates
```

I press "Select All" button for update, but it keeps showing that error. I have also take care of update everything before, but it continues failing.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087606/egit-requires-org-eclipse-team-core ?

Answer (score 2):

Your Eclipse version needs to be 3.8 or higher. You must have installed Indigo from the Software center in Ubuntu or Synaptic as that is what would have been installed. You can download Juno which would work for you from the [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) Project. It is a tar.gz that you just unarchive into the directory you want and run it. You can use the same workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the EGit Import Support feature when selecting what to install.  It is optional and appears to be not supported in indigo.