# Aptana Studio 3 GIT error on update

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, aptana, aptana3

When trying to update Aptana Studio, I'm getting errors:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.1.0.201310021548-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.1.0.201310021548-r)
  Missing requirement: Git Team Provider UI 3.1.0.201310021548-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 3.1.0.201310021548-r) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.team.core [3.6.100,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.1.0.201310021548-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.1.0.201310021548-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.ui [3.1.0.201310021548-r]

I'm running Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805.

What do I need to get this updated?

Comment: Try looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11098072/302485