# FDT5 EGit installation error

Tags: eclipse, egit, fdt

When I try to install EGit via the update URL or marketplace I get the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider
>   3.2.0.201312181205-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.2.0.201312181205-r)   Missing requirement: Git Team Provider UI 3.2.0.201312181205-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 3.2.0.201312181205-r) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.team.core [3.6.100,4.0.0)' but it could
>   not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.2.0.201312181205-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.2.0.201312181205-r)
>       To: org.eclipse.egit.ui [3.2.0.201312181205-r]

My FDT5 is up to date.

Can I somehow install the org.eclipse.team.core bundle to solve the dependency?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11087606/305973

Comment: It's a different error. Also the answer "Just deselect the checkbox, and installing should work." makes no sense to me. There is no checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, FDT ships on Eclipse Juno (4.2) on which EGit has tested to work smoothly.

You can install EGit by:

1. **Help** > **Install New Software**
2. Click on **Available Software Sites**
3. Check in **Juno** (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno)
4. Click OK to close
5. From **Work with** select choose **Juno**
6. Check in **Collaboration** > **Eclipse EGit**

We've also tested JGit to work smoothly.

Comment: even though I don't understand what is the difference this approach worked.

Comment: The problem you seemed to have is that you tried to install the version of the Git bundle incompatible with the rest of the setup. It is also why FDT team provides that update site in the list of update sites as a silent recommendation that you can turn on. I'm glad it worked out!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what FDT 5 is, but from the error it looks like it is based on an old version of the Eclipse Platform.

EGit 3.2 requires Eclipse Platform >= 3.8.2/4.2.2, see [What versions of Eclipse does EGit target?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F)  in the FAQ.

Either upgrade FDT or try installing an older version of EGit such as 2.3.1, see [Where can I find older releases of EGit?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F).

Comment: That seems to be it, the FDT5 seems to be built on Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: Do they provide an update site to install the plugins into a standard Eclipse?

Comment: Well that is what I hope them to answer here.

Comment: Current version of FDT ships on Eclipse 4.2.